# "Please make sure your passwords match" error on customer registration in Version. 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, password

I am using Magento version **1.9.0.1**. On new **customer registration**, I am getting **"Please make sure your passwords match"** error. I have tried different solutions, but nothing works, still same error appears.

Comment: "I have tried different solutions, but nothing works, still same error appears" which one ?

Comment: There are many questions regarding this issue.. I have read those issues..  I have added  <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" /> after <ul class="form-list"> in login.phtml.. and register.phtml . Added <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>  before </form> in register.phtml.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade your system?

Comment: No.. From starting only I am using version 1.9.0.1

Comment: FYI validation trigger on form submit not on lost focus of field can you confirm ?

Comment: That error message is displaying when I click on the submit button.. when page reloads.. i.e. on form submit.

Answer (score 4):

Check `register.phtml` name for Confirmation Password should be `confirmation`. 
Because `setConfirmation` method is used in `customer AccountController` in various places to set the confirmation value. 
If there is some mismatch try changing `setConfirmation` to `setPasswordConfirmation()` in `AccountController`.

Comment: Yes name for Confirmation Password is 'confirmation'. In AccountController.php setConfirmation is present at 4 to 5 places.

Comment: Changes setConfirmation to setPasswordConfirmation but still not workig.

Comment: @ved Try changing in file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php as well.

Comment: I have changed register.phtml with othe Magentor installation's register.phtml and Now it is working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer is a bit vague, it would be better to highlight when the confirmation field name changed in the recent patches rather than suggesting to "try" changing it.

Answer (score 2):

Its worked for me in Magento-1.9.3.4 by below changes in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/Accountcontroller.php`

```
$customer->setPasswordConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
```

to

```
$customer->setConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
```